# RowSet Returns From Inter-active queries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

New to Oracle, having loads of niggling troubles, strong in tSQL not in pl\SQL

I want to list the contents of a table in SQL Developer dependant on some pre-programmed variables, ultimately I would like this to be like a MS-SQL Stored Procedure where I call it passing parameters...

I get error ...an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

TIA - Andy

```
DECLARE
  tbl_name varchar2(30) := 'ALL';
  ix_name  varchar2(30) := 'ALL';
BEGIN
  SELECT table_name, index_name, monitoring
    FROM v$object_usage

   WHERE (table_name = UPPER(tbl_name) or UPPER(tbl_name) = 'ALL')
     AND (index_name = UPPER(ix_name) or UPPER(ix_name) = 'ALL');
END;
```

Comment: In _Oracle_ To return a rowset from a stored procedure to a host program one must return a cursor variable. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00605

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your select is fetching some data but you're not storing it into any variable.

Your select should be like,

```
SELECT table_name, index_name, monitoring
into var1,var2,var3
    FROM v$object_usage
```

But if your select returns more than one rows this will throw an error, so you might have to use collections in that case.

Comment: so stuff it into a temp table and select that at the end ?